# Как спарсить сайт Dns-shop.ru?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, парсер, python-2.x

Пробовал сделать так:

```
def parser(search):
    headers = {'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
               'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 YaBrowser/19.10.3.281 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'}
    url = 'https://www.dns-shop.ru/search/?q=' + search + '&p=1'
    sesia = requests.session()
    request = sesia.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5)
    soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
    products = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'catalog-item'})
```

Пробовал через Selenium:

```
def parser(search):
    url = 'https://www.dns-shop.ru/search/?q=' + search + '&p=1'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get(url)

    content = driver.page_source
    print(content)
```

В ответ получаю все кроме товаров, как я понял работает json. Подскажите пожалуйста как спарсить товар.
Выводит вот этот скрипт + футер

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create',  'UA-8349380-2', 'auto');
    ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
    ga('require', 'linkid');
    ga('require', 'ec');

    ga('set', 'dimension1', 'moscow');
    if (undefined !== window.COMMERCE_PARAM_BUY) {
        ga('set', 'dimension2', window.COMMERCE_PARAM_BUY);
    }


    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    /** @type {YandexDataLayer} */
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        try {
        var yaParams = {"city":"moscow"};
        (function(m,e,t,r,i,k,a) {
            m[i]=m[i]||function() {
                (m[i].a=m[i].a||[]).push(arguments);
            };
            m[i].l=1*new Date();
            if (undefined !== m.COMMERCE_PARAM_BUY) {
                yaParams.buy = m.COMMERCE_PARAM_BUY;
            }
            k=e.createElement(t),a=e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],k.async=1,k.src=r,a.parentNode.insertBefore(k,a)})
        (window, document, "script", "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js", "ym");
        ym(7967056, "init", {
            clickmap:true,
            trackLinks:true,
            accurateTrackBounce:true,
            webvisor:true,
            trackHash:true,
            ecommerce:"dataLayer",
            params:yaParams
        });
        window.yaCounterReachGoal = function(e, p) { ym(7967056, 'reachGoal', e, p); }
    } catch(e) {}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если указывать заголовок запроса `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'`, то в ответ придет `json`, иначе -- честный `html`.

Первый содержит сами данные поиска, второй -- данные поиска и много чего (header, footer, скрипты, и т.п.).

Поэтому, при получении ответа нужно использовать парсер `json`, а потом парсер `html`.

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6993f9a889a3050ee28cb73382698e87429da8fd/html_parsing/www_dns_shop_ru/search_products.py#L14)

```
import json
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def get_products(search: str) -> list:
    headers = {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0'
    }
    url = f'https://www.dns-shop.ru/search/?q={search}&p=1&order=popular&stock=all'
    session = requests.session()
    session.headers.update(headers)

    rs = session.get(url)
    data = json.loads(rs.text)

    root = BeautifulSoup(data['html'], 'html.parser')

    items = []

    for a in root.select('.product-info__title-link > a'):
        items.append(
            (a.get_text(strip=True), urljoin(rs.url, a['href']))
        )

    return items
```

Запуск:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = 'Видеокарты'
    items = get_products(name)

    print(f'Search {name!r}...')
    print(f'  Result ({len(items)}):')
    for title, url in items:
        print(f'    {title!r}: {url}')
    print()
```

Результат:

```
Search 'Видеокарты'...
  Result (18):
    'Видеокарта MSI AMD Radeon RX 570 ARMOR OC [RX 570 ARMOR 8G OC]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/2bec09e3fc2e3330/videokarta-msi-amd-radeon-rx-570-armor-oc-rx-570-armor-8g-oc/
    'Видеокарта MSI GeForce RTX 2060 Super VENTUS OC [RTX 2060 SUPER VENTUS OC]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/06580877a9c61b80/videokarta-msi-geforce-rtx-2060-super-ventus-oc-rtx-2060-super-ventus-oc/
    'Видеокарта MSI GeForce RTX 2070 Super GAMING X TRIO [RTX 2070 SUPER GAMING X TRIO]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/893d7d1698bb3332/videokarta-msi-geforce-rtx-2070-super-gaming-x-trio-rtx-2070-super-gaming-x-trio/
    'Видеокарта Palit GeForce RTX 2060 Gaming Pro [NE62060018J9-1062A]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/89eb26e2156d1b80/videokarta-palit-geforce-rtx-2060-gaming-pro-ne62060018j9-1062a/
    'Видеокарта Sapphire AMD Radeon RX 590 PULSE [11289-06-20G]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/d4aa3e2690ab1b80/videokarta-sapphire-amd-radeon-rx-590-pulse-11289-06-20g/
    'Видеокарта Palit GeForce GTX 1660 DUAL OC [NE51660S18J9-1161A]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/25db5664658c3332/videokarta-palit-geforce-gtx-1660-dual-oc-ne51660s18j9-1161a/
    'Видеокарта GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 1660 OC [GV-N1660OC-6GD]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/38d7d1eb43d73332/videokarta-gigabyte-geforce-gtx-1660-oc-gv-n1660oc-6gd/
    'Видеокарта MSI AMD Radeon RX 570 ARMOR OC [RX 570 ARMOR 4G OC]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/90db0b7a1f5f3330/videokarta-msi-amd-radeon-rx-570-armor-oc-rx-570-armor-4g-oc/
    'Видеокарта GIGABYTE AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT GAMING OC [GV-R57XTGAMING OC-8GD]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/ec8f0a1dbfde1b80/videokarta-gigabyte-amd-radeon-rx-5700-xt-gaming-oc-gv-r57xtgaming-oc-8gd/
    'Видеокарта GIGABYTE GeForce RTX 2060 Super GAMING OC [GV-N206SGAMING OC-8GC]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/bfa21bf998943332/videokarta-gigabyte-geforce-rtx-2060-super-gaming-oc-gv-n206sgaming-oc-8gc/
    'Видеокарта MSI GeForce GTX 1660 VENTUS XS 6G OCV1 [GTX 1660 VENTUS XS 6G OCV1]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/1ef66abccb1e3332/videokarta-msi-geforce-gtx-1660-ventus-xs-6g-ocv1-gtx-1660-ventus-xs-6g-ocv1/
    'Видеокарта MSI GeForce GTX 1660 VENTUS XS OC [GTX 1660 VENTUS XS 6G OC]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/849575aa4ac13332/videokarta-msi-geforce-gtx-1660-ventus-xs-oc-gtx-1660-ventus-xs-6g-oc/
    'Видеокарта KFA2 GeForce RTX 2070 Super EX - 1 Click OC [27ISL6MDU9EK]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/ea111905a77a1b80/videokarta-kfa2-geforce-rtx-2070-super-ex---1-click-oc-27isl6mdu9ek/
    'Видеокарта MSI GeForce GTX 1660 Ti GAMING X [GTX 1660 TI GAMING X 6G]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/b3643ee130d03332/videokarta-msi-geforce-gtx-1660-ti-gaming-x-gtx-1660-ti-gaming-x-6g/
    'Видеокарта Sapphire AMD Radeon RX 570 PULSE [11266-66-20G]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/5a1c9bea39693332/videokarta-sapphire-amd-radeon-rx-570-pulse-11266-66-20g/
    'Видеокарта MSI GeForce RTX 2060 Super GAMING X [RTX 2060 SUPER GAMING X]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/12eaefb3a9c71b80/videokarta-msi-geforce-rtx-2060-super-gaming-x-rtx-2060-super-gaming-x/
    'Видеокарта MSI GeForce GTX 1660 Ti ARMOR OC [GTX 1660 Ti ARMOR 6G OC]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/c1bedbe329171b80/videokarta-msi-geforce-gtx-1660-ti-armor-oc-gtx-1660-ti-armor-6g-oc/
    'Видеокарта Sapphire AMD Radeon RX 590 NITRO+ Special Edition OC [11289-01-20G]': https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/9013d2b9e6da1b80/videokarta-sapphire-amd-radeon-rx-590-nitro-special-edition-oc-11289-01-20g/
```

---

**PS.**

Вот так выглядит `print(rs.text)`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Подскажи, есть ли мануал на эту тему, или что гуглить чтобы разобраться подробнее

Comment: @максшелгунов, не знаю, я самоучка с таким хобби :) а так почитайте про регулярные выражения, xpath, css-селекторы и, скорее всего, понадобится про http-заголовки и про http(s) в частности, а также html, json, javascript

Comment: Большое спасибо !

Comment: Еще вопрос возник, начала вылеать ошибка:
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @gli9red Как спарсить цену товара, ее почему то не выдает?

Comment: @максшелгунов, скорее всего что-то не так с результатом запроса (выводите и смотрите `rs.text`), возможно сработала защита от ботов. Посмотрел в том, что возвращается из ajax запроса, а именно `<span class="product-price-placeholder" id="ajs-2d518983-d9ea-4955-86c3-c7d636e965fe"/>`, и цены не нашел там, выходит должен быть еще запрос, что цены вернет. Ведь, на странице результата поиска цены есть. Смотрите в инспекторе браузере (F12) на вкладке Сети какие запросы ходят

Comment: Я решил это по-другому, я захожу на ссылку товара и беру от туда

Comment: @максшелгунов, у `class=current-price-value` через атрибут `data-price-value` (https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/DNS%20price%20tracking/main.py#L32)?

Answer (score 2):

Мы можете работать с готовыми прайсами (например: https://www.dns-shop.ru/files/price/price-spb.zip), в место того чтобы делаться тысячи запросов к сайту. Ссылка для вашего города находиться в footer страницы

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать. Но я бы хотел все-таки узнать как обойти защиту,  будет полезно для меня

Comment: Возможно, что api поиска проверяет cookie\session\csrf-token\refer\browser 
 попробуйте повторить все эти заголовки при запросе

Comment: Как мне передавать csfr и куки, они же меняются каждый раз  ?